# Script to import txt files to Google Sheet (based on existing VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've have VBA code that imports some text files to Excel worksheet, but now I've come to implement it in Google Sheets to do the same. Can someone help me convert the VBA to GAS ?

Code:

```vb
Sub ImportTXTFiles()
 Dim fso As Object
 Dim xlsheet As Worksheet
 Dim qt As QueryTable
 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim txtfilesToOpen As Variant, txtfile As Variant

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 txtfilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
             (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
              MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")
 LastRow = 1
 For Each txtfile In txtfilesToOpen
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & txtfile, _
      Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1))
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = " "

        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    LastRow = LastRow + 1
    For Each qt In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
        qt.Delete
    Next qt
 Next txtfile

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 MsgBox "Successfully imported text files!", vbInformation, "SUCCESSFUL IMPORT"

 Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: That's not VBScript, more likely VBA in Excel.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question. • You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) • Give it a try yourself before asking us to do it.

Comment: Why do you need a script? You can just open the files with Spreadsheed as soon as these files uploaded on Google Drive and have '.csv' extension

Comment: I need script because I have over 200 small txt files, their content sometimes change. I want to automate importing and refreshing data. BTW import function in GS works with one file only, you can not select multiple files at once.

Comment: Note that we cannot translate this code for you. We can only help you if you did the translation yourself and got stuck or errors in a specific point.

Comment: Ok Pᴇʜ , I understand.

Answer (score 0):

well task is finished. First of all it was necessary to build some kind of UI to have possibility to upload .txt files to Google Drive. After that it's possible to import them to the sheet (there are also 2 other functions: delete files on drive and refresh).
Ok, the code:

*.gs code:*

```
function onOpen() {
openHTML();
showSidebar();
listFilesFromDrive(); }

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function listFilesFromDrive() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange("A2:D").clear();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); // I change the folder ID  here 
  var list = [];
  list.push(['Nazwa pliku log']); //,'ID','Size']);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    var row = []
    row.push(file.getName())
    list.push(row);
  }
  sh.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);
  importFilesContent();
}

function importFilesContent() {
  var i = 2;
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); // I change the folder ID  here 
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()){
    file = files.next();
    var contents = file.getBlob().getDataAsString().trim();
    var lines = contents.split(",");
    contents = lines.map(function(lin){return lin.split(" ")});
    sh.getRange(i, 2, contents.length, contents[0].length).setValues(contents);
    i = i + 1;
  } 
}

function saveFile(obj) {
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(obj.data), obj.mimeType, obj.fileName);
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<script>google.script.host.close();</script>');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output, 'Uploading...');
  return DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').createFile(blob).getId();
}

function openHTML() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Upload Menu')
      .addItem('Pokaz pasek boczny', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index.html')
      .setTitle('Pasek boczny upload');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .showSidebar(html);
}

function delFiles() {
      var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
      var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<script>google.script.host.close();</script>');
      while (myFolder.getFiles().hasNext()) {
        const file = myFolder.getFiles().next();
        Logger.log('Moving file to trash: ', file);
        file.setTrashed(true);
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output, 'Deleting...');
      }
}
```

*index.html code:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input name="file" id="files" type="file" multiple>
    <input type='button' value='Upload' onclick='getFiles()'>
    <input type='button' value='Delete Files on Drive' onclick='delFilesOnDrive()'>
    <input type='button' value='Refresh' onclick='filesRefresh()'>
    
    <script>
    
    function delFilesOnDrive() {
      google.script.run.delFiles();  
    }

    function filesRefresh() {
      google.script.run.listFilesFromDrive();  
    }
    
    function getFiles() {
    const f = document.getElementById('files');
    [...f.files].forEach((file, i) => {
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = (e) => {
      const data = e.target.result.split(",");
      const obj = {fileName: f.files[i].name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]};
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((id) => {
        console.log(id);
      }).saveFile(obj);
    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
    
    }
 
    </script>
  
  </body>
</html>
```